# Use pipeline to show filtered data and data that was filtered away

Tags: powershell, scripting, pipeline

I have a powershell project that I am working on that is reading data from a database using a function, then I am using the pipeline to filter that data to find what I want. One of the requirements is that I should display all irrelevant data as well as the data that the gets filtered.

```
Get-Foo($Connection) |
Group Bar|
? Count -eq 2 |
? {$_.Group.Foobar -contains "A" -and $_.Group.Foobar -contains "B" -or $_.Group.Foobar -contains "A" -and $_.Group.Foobar -contains "C"} |
```

So basically I want to output all records that contain either only A and B or only A and C, But I also want to display all of the records that don't contain this.

```
Sample Data:
(A, B, C, D, E)
(A, B)
(A, B, C, D)
(A, B, E)
(A)
(A, C)

Current Output:
(A, B)
(A, C)

Required Output
(A, B, C, D, E)
(A, B, C, D)
(A, B, E)
(A) - List all the false outcomes of filtering
(A, B) - Then list the true
(A, C)
```

Comment: Why not loop over the data with an `if` statement and create two arrays, one with the data that matches the current `where` filter and one that doesn't?

Comment: @PetSerAl How would I go about then displaying the objects that get filtered out?

Comment: Your sample and required output don't seem correct to me?! All but one sample *(A)* contains (A and B) or (A and C)?

Comment: @LievenKeersmaekers The filtered results must contain both of the letters (A and B) or (A and C) and the count must be 2. So when the data is filtered, only (A,B) (A,C) Values will be returned. I have this working with my real data. I just need a way to keep all of the results that are filtered away, like shown.

Comment: Ah, I've missed the count, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Group-Object` instead `Where-Object`. In that case you will have two group: one for false condition and other for true.

```
$SampleData=@'
Bar,Foobar
1,A
1,B
1,C
1,D
1,E
2,A
2,B
3,A
3,B
3,C
4,D
5,A
5,B
5,E
6,A
7,A
7,C
'@|ConvertFrom-Csv

$SampleData|
Group-Object Bar|
# I am join both your conditions into one.
Group-Object {($_.Count -eq 2) -and (
                   (($_.Group.Foobar -contains 'A') -and ($_.Group.Foobar -contains 'B')) -or
                   (($_.Group.Foobar -contains 'A') -and ($_.Group.Foobar -contains 'C'))
              )}|
# To have false before true.
Sort-Object {$_.Values[0]}|
# Expand groups.
Select-Object @{Name='Condition';Expression={$_.Values[0]}} -ExpandProperty Group|
# Display results to user.
Format-Table -GroupBy Condition
```